# Netty - Using the EventLoop to combine operations?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I came across [this](http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-facebook-eng-netty/slides.html#28.0) suggestion to combine operations by using the underlying channel's EventLoop to execute them together. In the example provided, write operations are used. It was my assumption was that write operations were already done asynchronously on an I/O thread (the EventLoop?) provided by Netty... so why is it necessary to execute multiple operations using the EventLoop the channel is assigned to?

Also, if doing operations on the EventLoop thread provides some sort of performance benefit then why does that only apply to multiple operations and not single ones?

Any clarification would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand when you call this code outside of **EventLoop**:

```
channel.write(msg1);
channel.writeAndFlush(msg3);
```

It under the hood transforms to:

```
channel.eventLoop().execute(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    channel.write(msg1);
  }
});
channel.eventLoop().execute(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    channel.writeAndFlush(msg3);
  }
});
```

So for reducing dispatching overhead it is better to combine them to one:

```
channel.eventLoop().execute(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    channel.write(msg1);
    channel.writeAndFlush(msg3);
  }
});
```

Comment: But wouldn't the second piece of code just translate to the same thing as the first one, just executed within the EventLoop thread? I'm confused

Comment: @lare96, it would be two `Runnable`s - two different tasks in eventLoops queue consuming the memory and requiring dispatching. Event loop could process another channels between executions of this tasks, so the client could receive result latter